# PHP: how can I get sum from list()?

Tags: php, list, explode

It's taking me quite some time to solve this problem and decided to ask for help.

I have a php code here to calculate total hours and minutes. I know I should have used php `SUM(totalhours)` but I want to try it different way.

`$query_hours` gets column 'totalhours'

```
foreach($query_hours->result() as $row){
    $tt = $row->totalhours;     // 10:58 | 09:20 | 10:00
    list($tt1,$tt2) = explode(':', $tt);  //$tt1 = 10 | 09 | 10
}
```

the thing now is how can I get the sum of `$tt1` which is 29?
I tried `array_sum($tt1)` but I got an error, something like invalid argument, string given. Already did an initialization `$thours = array($tt1)` before using `array_sum()` but still got another error :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you want to do it the way you are and don't want to use Mysql `SUM()`, you can use a variable to hold the sum over the loop

```
$sum=0;
foreach($query_hours->result() as $row){
   $tt = $row->totalhours;     // 10:58 | 09:20 | 10:00
   list($tt1,$tt2) = explode(':', $tt);  //$tt1 = 10 | 09 | 10
   $sum+=$tt1;
 }
echo $sum;
```

Comment: my bad, I did that same thing earlier it's just that i placed $sum=0 inside the foreach, no wonder $sum always returns the last value (10) :3

Comment: Yep, if you set it to 0 inside the loop every time you'd surely get that :)

Comment: I'm crying on my NOOBility :'(

Comment: Dont sweat over that. Thats how we learn and improve, now you'll never make that mistake again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
$total=0;
foreach($query_hours->result() as $row){
   $tt = $row->totalhours;     // 10:58 | 09:20 | 10:00
   list($tt1,$tt2) = explode(':', $tt);  //$tt1 = 10 | 09 | 10
   $total+=$tt1;
 }
echo $total; //your result here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem, try this:

```
$sum=0;
foreach($query_hours->result() as $row){
   $tt = $row->totalhours;     // 10:58 | 09:20 | 10:00
   list($tt1,$tt2) = explode(':', $tt);  //$tt1 = 10 | 09 | 10
   $sum+=$tt1;
 }
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get when using `array_sum` ? as long as you give it an array there shouldn't be any errors.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($query_hours->result() as $row){
    $tt = $row->totalhours;     // 10:58 | 09:20 | 10:00
    $sum += array_sum(explode(':', $tt));  //$tt1 = 10 | 09 | 10
}
```